# Error in BOWImgDescriptorExtractor in EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I get the following error when I try to invoke the `BOWImgDescriptorExtractor` compute method with `BriefDescriptorExtractor` and `BruteForceMatcher`.

> An unhandled exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
>   Additional information: OpenCV: type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U)

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: I was able to fix this issue. The issue was with type == src2.type(). The feature extractor(SIFT) I used to create vocabulary was different than the feature extractor(BRIEF) I used as argument given for definition in BOWImgDescriptorExtractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue. The issue was with type == src2.type(). The feature extractor(SIFT) I used to create vocabulary was different than the feature extractor(BRIEF) I used as argument given for definition in BOWImgDescriptorExtractor.

Answer (score -1):

This is the most likely cause: **(type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U)**

The image must be of 32-bit floating point depth, or of 8-bit, unsigned char depth.

Check this out:
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images

Comment: I have given "Byte" here which was correct. :) Anyway, your link was helpful to learn about images. Thank you perfanoff.